# Xcode Swift IOS Eureka LabelRow not updating title when view is reloaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, eureka-forms

The LabelRow $0.title is not being updated when returning to the view that contains the following code.

How can I have LabelRow update it's title after returning from a 'pushed' view that changes a global variable?

```
form +++

        Section("Current Person")
        <<< LabelRow {
            $0.title = currentPersonName  // "currentPersonName" is a global variable
            $0.tag = "Person"
        }.cellUpdate { cell, _ in
            cell.row.title = currentPersonName // set title to "currentPersonName"
            print("cellUpdate shows \(currentPersonName)") // verify "currentPersonName" change
        }.onCellSelection { _, _ in
            // the following view controller sets "currentPersonName" to something new
            let PersonPicker = PersonPicker()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(PersonPicker, animated: false)
            print("onCellSelection shows \(currentPersonName)") // verify "currentPersonName" change
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to 'fix' it:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    if let row = self.form.rowBy(tag: "Person")
    {
        row.title = currentPersonName
        row.reload()
    }
}
```

But is that the best solution?